# Data from API parsing in for cycle with bad result

Tags: android, api, android-studio

I parse data from API (https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/standings) in for cycle. In debug mode, I see, that data are correct from API, but when I write first record to "tabulkaTimov", and for cycle have j=1 (j=2,j=3, ... etc), my first record is replace by next team.

Screenshot of my app:
https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2019/01/03/bbEf.png

It is table of NHL league.

```
public static List<TableTeamsModel> convertJsonToTableTeams(JsonObject data){
    List<TableTeamsModel> tabulkaTimov = new ArrayList<>();
    JsonArray pocetDivizii = data.get("records").getAsJsonArray();

    for(int i=0;i<pocetDivizii.size();i++){

       TableTeamsModel tabulka = new TableTeamsModel();

       JsonObject division = pocetDivizii.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
       tabulka.setDivisionName(division.get("division").getAsJsonObject().get("name").getAsString());

       JsonArray teams = division.get("teamRecords").getAsJsonArray();

        for(int j=0;j<teams.size();j++) {

            JsonObject teamRecords = teams.get(j).getAsJsonObject();
            tabulka.setTeamName(teamRecords.get("team").getAsJsonObject().get("name").getAsString());

            tabulka.setGoalsGot(teamRecords.get("goalsAgainst").getAsInt());
            tabulka.setGoalsScored(teamRecords.get("goalsScored").getAsInt());
            tabulka.setPoints(teamRecords.get("points").getAsInt());
            tabulka.setGamesPlayed(teamRecords.get("gamesPlayed").getAsInt());

            tabulkaTimov.add(tabulka);
        }
    }
    return tabulkaTimov;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are creating a new *tabulka* object outside of your for loop and then add it multiple times in the same arraylist.
This will add it once (reference) and just update its content.

Here is what you can do

```
public static List<TableTeamsModel> convertJsonToTableTeams(JsonObject data){
    List<TableTeamsModel> tabulkaTimov = new ArrayList<>();
    JsonArray pocetDivizii = data.get("records").getAsJsonArray();

    for(int i=0;i<pocetDivizii.size();i++){

        // Remove the creation of the tabulka object from here

        JsonObject division = pocetDivizii.get(i).getAsJsonObject()
        JsonArray teams = division.get("teamRecords").getAsJsonArray();

        for(int j=0;j<teams.size();j++) {

            JsonObject teamRecords = teams.get(j).getAsJsonObject();

            // And then put the object creation here.
            // as we did't have it above, the division name has to be set here too.

            TableTeamsModel tabulka = new TableTeamsModel();
            tabulka.setDivisionName(division.get("name").getAsString());
            tabulka.setTeamName(teamRecords.get("team").getAsJsonObject().get("name").getAsString());
            tabulka.setGoalsGot(teamRecords.get("goalsAgainst").getAsInt());
            tabulka.setGoalsScored(teamRecords.get("goalsScored").getAsInt());
            tabulka.setPoints(teamRecords.get("points").getAsInt());
            tabulka.setGamesPlayed(teamRecords.get("gamesPlayed").getAsInt());

            tabulkaTimov.add(tabulka);
        }
    }
    return tabulkaTimov;
}
```

This way you will add a **different/new object** each time you go over the loop into your ArrayList; - instead of adding the same reference of the same object every time with its data updated.